# Proving prefix language of a given language is not decidable

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, turing-machines, decidability

I'm aware that there is a question already about prefixes and decidability but it didn't really help me. I'm given a language L that consists of the strings $R(M)1^n$ such that execution of the Turing machine M with empty input string $\epsilon$ terminates within n steps. I need to prove that the Prefix language $L' = \{w \in \Sigma^* |  \exists u \in \Sigma^*:wu\in L\}$ is not decidable. I've tried to reduce it to the halting problem or look for a property that lets me use Rice's theorem but I was unable to reach anything meaningful, what am I missing?

Comment: But isn't the reduction to the halting problem straightforward?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen how?

Comment: If $M$ is a Turing machine then $R(M)\in L'$ iff $M$ halts on empty input in finitely many steps ...

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand know